# What type of proposition are these?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Consider the proposition:

"The sun rises from the east."

It is true.
So, the second proposition:

"The sun rises from the east is true."

It is also true.
So, the third proposition:

"The sun rises from the east is true, is true."

....,so on and so forth.

But the meaning of the later propositions is more and more obscure. Is there some book discussing this kind of propositions?

Comment: Not omitting the inner quotation marks makes clearer the recursion (that the propositions are just becoming more meta).

Comment: @RyanG Can you please introduce some book on  meta proposition and the relation between proposition and meta proposition?

Comment: The meaning of the later propositions become more and more obscure, because what they refer to becomes less and less clear with more and more referents, or as one ascends the metalogical ladder and abstraction level increases. If I know that she knows that he knows something about her relationship with me, there's a lot more to keep track of than if she knows something and that's it. Also, what do you mean by "this kind of proposition"? Why we would assume that a proposition about a proposition about a thing is like a proposition about a proposition about a proposition about a thing?

Comment: A proposition about a proposition about a thing is at a different level of abstraction than a proposition about a proposition about a proposition about a thing, and thus those two propositons very well be of different kinds.

Comment: The terminology of proposition was originated from ancient Greek syllogistic logic and is subtly different from mere sentences or statements, some modern logicians and philosophers regard it simply as evident judgement. So seemingly different sentences you write may not necessarily mean different proposition types. If two different sentences are deemed to be evident by the same evidence, then they must have the same type according to the [deflationary theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflationary_theory_of_truth) advocated by Frege and Ramsey.